# Create a type with Specific keys from other type

Tags: typescript

let's say I have this type:

```
interface Koko {
 a?:string,
 b?:number, 
 c?:string[],
 d?:number[]
}
```

and I wish to create whitelist type for specific keys out of this type :

```
interface PartialKoko {
 a?:string,
 b?:number, 
}
```

so if I send c|d - I will receive error
and if I a as string or b as a number it will pass the type check.

is there a way to do it without creating a new type?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for [`Pick`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Pick<Type, Keys>

create allow keys

```
interface Koko {
 a?:string,
 b?:number, 
 c?:string[],
 d?:number[]
}

    type AllowedKeys = "a" | "b";
    
    type PartialKoko = Pick<Koko, AllowedKeys>;
```